# ValueError: Invalid token $end in rply parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I'm making a parser with rply, and am getting the following error.

```py
PS E:\ParserAndLexer> & C:/Python38/python.exe e:/ParserAndLexer/lite/main.py
e:\ParserAndLexer\lite\main_parser.py:82: ParserGeneratorWarning: Token 'EQUALS' is unused
  return self.pg.build()
e:\ParserAndLexer\lite\main_parser.py:82: ParserGeneratorWarning: Token 'ELSE' is unused
  return self.pg.build()
e:\ParserAndLexer\lite\main_parser.py:82: ParserGeneratorWarning: Token '$end' is unused
  return self.pg.build()
e:\ParserAndLexer\lite\main_parser.py:82: ParserGeneratorWarning: Production 'block' is not reachable
  return self.pg.build()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/ParserAndLexer/lite/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(parser.parse(tokens).eval())
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\rply\parser.py", line 60, in parse
    self.error_handler(lookahead)
  File "e:\ParserAndLexer\lite\main_parser.py", line 79, in error_handle
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid token {token} {token.value} at {token.getsourcepos()}")
ValueError: Invalid token Token('$end', '$end') $end at None
```

This is happening when I try to parse

```
if 5 == 5 {
  print("True");
}
```

My code works fine though when I parse single line if statements, like

```
if 5 == 5 {print("True");}
```

This is the line where im parsing the if statement. https://github.com/AbooMinister25/ToyLang/blob/1a412b4074e4fd059c53716d21691db1d1919a05/lite/main_parser.py#L31

Heres the entire github page: https://github.com/AbooMinister25/ToyLang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is not in your parser; it's in [the code which calls the parser](https://github.com/AbooMinister25/ToyLang/blob/master/lite/main.py#L15) in `main.py`, which looks roughly like this (with some irrelevant lines removed):

```py
with open('test.lite', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        tokens = lexer.lex(line)
        print(parser.parse(tokens).eval())
```

That code reads the entire file, splits it into lines, and then attempts to parse one line at a time. So the first call to parse attempts to make sense of the first line in the file: `if 5 == 5 {`.

That is evidently not a valid `if` statement, so when the parser reaches the end of the token list (the `$end` token), it signals a syntax error.

The solution is simple. Don't split the file into lines; read the entire input as a single string; tokenise it, and parse the tokens in a single call to parse.